# Content Porter 2009 SP2 | Logging Configuration missing | Executing cpcmd.exe

Tags: content-porter-2009

I am trying to execute CPCMD.EXE command and my requirement is to log the output and error in a file of cpcmd.exe.

But when i am trying to run CPCMD.exe with the invalid user credential instead of giving me Login failure error it is throwing "[ConfigurationErrorsException: The configuration section for Logging cannot be found in the configuration source.]".

So what entry I need to put to resolve the same and in which config?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this section to your app.config:

```
<!-- Necessary for Tridion Logging --> <section 
name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" 
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Configu 
rationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"/> 
<section name="loggingConfiguration" 
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.Loggin 
gSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"/> 
<!-- until here -->
```

And then add this config as well:

```
<!-- Necessary to connect to Tridion --> 
<enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource selectedSource="Tridion Logging"> 
<sources> <clear/> <add name="Tridion Logging" 
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.SystemC 
onfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"/> 
</sources> </enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource> 
<loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" 
tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" 
logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="false"> <listeners> <add name="Tridion 
Console Trace Listener" 
listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configur 
ation.CustomTraceListenerData, 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" 
traceOutputOptions="None" 
type="Tridion.Logging.TridionConsoleTraceListener, Tridion.Common, 
Version=2.0.139.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" 
initializeData="" formatter="Trace Text Formatter"/> <add name="Tridion 
Debug Trace Listener" 
listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configur 
ation.CustomTraceListenerData, 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" 
traceOutputOptions="None" 
type="Tridion.Logging.TridionDebugTraceListener, Tridion.Common, 
Version=2.0.139.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" 
initializeData="" formatter="Trace Text Formatter"/> <add 
EventLog="Tridion" 
listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configur 
ation.CustomTraceListenerData, 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" 
traceOutputOptions="None" 
type="Tridion.Logging.TridionEventLogTraceListener, Tridion.Common, 
Version=2.0.139.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" 
name="Tridion Event Log" initializeData="" formatter="Tridion Text 
Formatter"/> <add fileName="D:\log\Tridion.ContentManager.log" 
header="----------------------------------------" 
footer="----------------------------------------" formatter="" 
listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configur 
ation.FlatFileTraceListenerData, 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" 
traceOutputOptions="None" 
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatF 
ileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" 
name="Tridion CM Log File"/> </listeners> <formatters> <add 
template="{message}" 
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextForma 
tter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" name="Trace Text 
Formatter"/> <add template="{message}&#xA;&#xA;Component: 
{keyvalue(component)}&#xA;Errorcode: {keyvalue(errorcode)}&#xA;User: 
{keyvalue(username)}&#xA;&#xA;{keyvalue(stacktrace)}" 
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextForma 
tter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" name="Tridion Text 
Formatter"/> </formatters> <categorySources> <add switchValue="All" 
name="General"/> </categorySources> <specialSources> <allEvents 
switchValue="Warning" name="All Events"> <listeners> <add name="Tridion 
Event Log"/> </listeners> </allEvents> <notProcessed switchValue="All" 
name="Unprocessed Category"/> <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging 
Errors &amp; Warnings"/> </specialSources> </loggingConfiguration> <!-- 
until here -->
```